# Why are my Stack Exchange accounts not associated?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

How do I add more accounts to my Stack Overflow email, like how to get the accounts to all be listed?

I am also on Math.SE, and Stack Exchange, but under "Accounts" in my profile it only shows my Stack Overflow account. Why is that?

Comment: By Math Overflow do you mean `http://math.stackexchange.com` or `http://mathoverflow.net/`?

Answer (score 2):

Your accounts *are* associated:

[image: Sean's accounts]

When you register to a new SE site, just use the same method you did to register for your first account—If you linked your Gmail, then link your Gmail. Afterwards, you can add as many accounts as you need to to your SE account.